Grafana not retrieving specified time range from MariaDB
I store home automation data in a MariaDB table. The time column is converted to UTC before writing and should be converted back to local time zone when reading. However, when I select "Last 3h", I only get 1h of data (I'm in UTC+2 at the moment), or 2h of data when DST is off. For example, at 16:30h in the afternoon, I'll get data between 15:30h and 16:30h. The plot, however, is scaled to 13:30h-16:30h and therefore is mostly empty. When I choose "Last 6h" I get the last 4h of data, and so on. The query I'm using is simple:
SELECT
  time AS "time",
  total_power_1 AS "WP"
FROM data
WHERE
  $__timeFilter(time)
ORDER BY time

and the plot definition in Grafana is equally simple, it's just a time series. Selecting periods shorter than "Last 3h" will not work at the moment, because the DB will return no data. Grafana's time zone is set to "browser", and the DB's time zone is set to the host's (which is UTC+2 at the moment).
Similarly, when I choose an absolute time range (eg, by choosing "Last 24h" and then zooming in to any 3h time range) I will also only get 1h of data at the moment, or 2h during periods without DST.
I have changed the data source's time zone from "Europe/Berlin" to "UTC", but this only resulted in a different set of rows to be retrieved when selecting "Last 3h": it's then the data from now-3h to now-2h, and again the x-axis span is 3h and therefore the plot is mostly empty. I have also experimented with time zone conversion in the SQL query, with no success.
I don't get it - how can I debug this problem? I tried to look at the query Grafana sends to MariaDB and cranked the debug level up to "trace", to no avail.
I'm not very good with Grafana and data bases; this is a hobby project. But I have a feeling that the effect is caused by some simple setting or me misunderstanding how things in Grafana or MariaDB work. Can anybody give a hint?

"The time column is converted to UTC before writing"  - that seems to be not working right. What is difference of the latest time in your table and currwnt unix timestamp?

Panel's menu has Inspect option. Check both query and results. Probably query fetches correct amount of data, and it is simply not visualized due to incorrect time shift. Also, if your data is in utc, data source should have utc configured.

So at 13:06:40 I selected "Last 3h" and the query issued by Grafana contained WHERE  time BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1727597200) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1727608000)
The two timestamps correspond to 10:06:40 and 13:06:40, and in this time the DB had only 1h worth of data, because the times are stored in UTC and ended at 11:06:04 UTC.
So it appears I need to tell Grafana to convert the times to UTC first (08:06:40 - 11:06:40 and then to construct the query.

I found a workaround at https://community.grafana.com/t/timefilter-does-not-produce-the-correct-time-range-in-sql/20841/6. This does the trick. Thanks for helping me debug this!
